# Constructing a product of commuting operators with certain properties

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Motived by elementary examples I wanted to find an example of a pair of commuting operators $A$ and $B$ with the following properties.  $A$ is left invertible, but not right invertible, and $B$ is right invertible but not left invertible. So far most examples of commuting operators are normal operators, and for them this isn't possible.

A hint towards the right literature would be great.